# How to group by one column with multi column query in hive

Tags: mysql, group-by, hive, multiple-columns

Ihave the follwing data:

| ID | Date1 | Date2 | Date3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022/01/01 | null | null |
| 1 | null | 2021/04/01 | null |
| 2 | 2022/03/01 | null | null |
| 2 | null | 2021/06/01 | null |
| 3 | 2022/01/01 | null | null |
| 4 | null | 2021/04/01 | null |

and I'm trying to get the following result:

| ID | Date1 | Date2 | Date3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022/01/01 | 2021/04/01 | null |
| 2 | 2022/03/01 | 2021/06/01 | null |
| 3 | 2022/01/01 | null | null |
| 4 | null | 2021/04/01 | null |

trying group by ID, isn't working as I get the error expression not in group by key.

Any help is well received.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate by the `ID` column and then take the `MAX()` of the other three columns:

```sql
SELECT ID, MAX(Date1) AS Date1, MAX(Date2) AS Date2, MAX(Date3) AS Date3
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

Note that the `MAX()` aggregate function will by default ignore `NULL` values.  Therefore, the non `NULL` values from each pair of similar `ID` records will be retained in the above query.